# Understanding Square Root rules to understand an equation

Tags: roots, fractions

So this is an equation from one of the solutions in my textbook that I am trying to understand as part of solving a cholesky-factorization problem:

$$\sqrt{18-(\frac{a}{\sqrt2})^2} = \sqrt{\frac{36-a^2}{\sqrt2}} $$

Which square root rule applies here? Feels like I am missing some basics...

Comment: The equation is not correct.  The $\sqrt{2}$ on the right should be a $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it *isn't* true. 
$$\sqrt{18-\left(\frac a{\sqrt2}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{36-a^2}2}$$

Notice the $2$ in the right hand side as opposed to $\sqrt2$

Comment: Thank you, this drove me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{18-\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt2}\right)^2} = \sqrt{18-\frac{a^2}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{36-a^2}{2}};$$

as pointed out by @John Wayland Bales in a comment to the question, $\sqrt2$ on the right side of the equation in the question should be $2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is $$18-\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=18-\frac{a^2}{2}=\frac{36-a^2}{2}$$

Comment: I think you meant $36 \mathbf - a^2$

Comment: Yes I meant this, thank you for your hint!